# Не работают стандартные сочетания клавиш Qt-приложения в Mac OS X,

Tags: c++, qt, mac

Создал приложение на Qt для OS X, но стандартные сочетания клавиш для закрытия и сжатия окон не работают, из-за этого приложение не будет принято в Mac App Store. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, стандартные сочетания клавиш действительно мало поддерживаются. Но их можно добавить самостоятельно в конструкторе каждого `QMainWindow`:

```
#include <QShortcut>

MyWindow::MyWindow (QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
#ifdef TARGET_OS_MAC
    new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+M"), this, SLOT(showMinimized()));
    new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+W"), this, SLOT(close()));
#endif
}
```

Обратите внимание, что название `Ctrl` трактуется как `Cmd` на клавиатуре Mac. (Для самой клавиши `Ctrl` в Qt используется название `Meta`.)